# How to extract the text from the below html tag using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to get the text value of nested div class

I tired using the below Xpath, but it seems to not work `//div[contains(@class, 'barone'and text='Guru99 Bank')]`

```
<div>
<h2 class="barone" style="font-size:27px;font-weight:700;padding: 10px;">Guru99 Bank</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what are you looking for?

```
div/h2[@class="barone"]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to extract the text - Guru99 Bank

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi, this XPath returns you exactly what you want. Test it.

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi FYI  If you are using selenium and Java with `findElement(By.xpath())` then you have to get the text form the element as findElement will return only element not text `driver.findElement(By.xpath(div/h2[@class="barone"])).text()`.

Comment: @Bor Laze, Thanks for your solution. it worked!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you are trying to **retrieve** the text use the below:

`WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='barone']"));`

`System.out.Println(ele.getText());`

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to use one of the following css selectors. The "." is a class selector.

```
.barone
```

or

```
h2.barone
```